# Link a widget or find the php that creates the widgets

Tags: widgets, links

I would like to make the entire widget a link. Ideally, I would like to find the php file that has created the widget and then modify that.

**Q**: Is there a way to backtrace the HTML to find what php created it?

**Q**: Is there a typical location that widget php files are located. I have looked in the body, header, for a widget.php.

I am using Responsive theme.

Answer (score 1):

If the widget is part of the wordpress core, you can see its source in `wp-includes/default-widgets.php`.

If it came with a theme or plugin, you can find the code there. Sometimes widgets will be in an obviously-named widgets.php, but other times you'll have to hunt for them. At some point, each widget has to be registered by calling `register_widget`. You can use the command line tool `grep` to find the `register_widget` call in the plugin/theme.

Sample grep syntax:

```
cd wp-content/plugins/pluginname
grep -r 'register_widget' .
```

If the machine you're on doesn't have grep, most IDEs also contain tools for searching through your code. Eclipse (multi OS), Textmate2 (OSX), and Notepad++ (Windows) are a few of my personal favorites. To that end, the more recent versions of OSX and Windows do a half-decent job of searching within files from right within Finder / Windows Explorer.

As far as getting a backtrace, [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) is a very powerful tool for figuring out just what a page is doing. You can use [remote debugging](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/remote) with one of the supported IDEs to really dive into your code.